# Unable to crawl when start_requests is overrided

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to attach the start URL as metadata to the requests by overriding `start_requests`, but the spider appears to refuse crawling other pages beside the start URLs. Does anyone know how to have metadata in the requests and crawl outside of the start URLs?

Thank you

```py
class TSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrapes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrapes.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*page.*']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=parse_item, meta={'start_url': url})


    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = {}
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['start_url'] = response.meta['start_url']
        yield item
```

Comment: Do you want the meta data for all the requests, or just the first one?

Comment: If you are trying to crawl pages outside of the domain.... remove the allowed_domains attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the callback in `start_requests` method, remove it.

If you want to add the start url to every request you can do one of the following:

**Method 1:** use [process_request](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) (better than method 2).

```py
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


def process_request(request, response):
    request.meta['start_url'] = response.request.meta.get('start_url')
    return request


class TSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*page.*']), callback='parse_item', follow=True, process_request=process_request),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, meta={'start_url': url})

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['start_url'] = response.request.meta.get('start_url')
        yield item
```

**Method 2:** overwrite [_requests_to_follow](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/spiders/crawl.html#CrawlSpider) method.

```py
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class TSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 't'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'.*page.*']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, meta={'start_url': url})

    def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
        if not isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
            return
        seen = set()
        for rule_index, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
            links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                     if lnk not in seen]
            for link in rule.process_links(links):
                seen.add(link)
                request = self._build_request(rule_index, link)
                request.meta['start_url'] = response.meta.get('start_url')  # I added just this one line
                yield rule.process_request(request, response)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = dict()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['start_url'] = response.meta.get('start_url')
        yield item
```